# Can I transfer drivers from windows.old to windows?

Tags: drivers

I grabbed a used computer from a friend that has a video card with HDMI on it, and an unregistered copy of Windows 7.
 I installed Windows Vista (what originally was supposed to be on the machine) having it hooked up to my TV (only thing with HDMI).
 All was well until it needed to reboot. When it did, my TV says unsupported signal. I hooked up my computer monitor using the VGA cable, and got no signal.
 I then removed the video card, and then the VGA cable worked. I finished updating Vista, and now I still cannot use the video card. When I plug it in, VGA no longer works, and my TV still says unsupported signal. I googled this issue and have now set the resolution to the lowest setting and the hertz to 60. Still same problem. I even went into the BIOS and have it boot from the motherboard first, but now my computer nor TV will recognize it being there. I believe its a driver problem, but I cannot download the driver without the computer recognizing it being there. But when I plug it in, and have it boot from there, I cannot use the VGA. See the problem.

So how can I get the driver installed? When I installed Vista, all of the old Windows files got saved as .old. Can I copy from there to fix this?

Comment: Paragraphs instead of a wall of text is always more readable. Also, how about letting us know what graphics card you have?

Comment: Its not clear the reason you feel its important that the computer has an unregistered copy of Windows 7.  This seems like a driver problem, specific information about the hardware, would be required to advise.  What makes you think the required driver is in Windows.old?

Answer (score 1):

Open the device manager and try to update drivers on the complaining hardware.  Tell Windows to search the windows.old directory and all subdirectories for drivers.

I tried copying files myself before I came to my senses, in a quite similar situation.